# Can I use Soot to find potential execution paths and resource usages given a starting class or method?

Tags: java, soot

Can I use the Soot framework to perform, at the Ubuntu command line, analyses on Java source code such as

*Find all socket usages or disk writes that may result from executing this method* or *Find all disk writes potentially generated by the implementation of this class*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But of course it does not do exactly that out of the box. You'd have to extend it.